# jquery append <li> tag to <ul> tag using class

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a dynamic form from a json array using jquery.

I have the below code to display the form:

```js
var data=[
 {"type":"dropdown","label":"Dropdown","req":0,
  "choices":[
   {"label":"choice1","sel":0,"notification":0,
    "subOptions":[
     {"NoteLabel":"choice1-Notes1","NoteValue":"","reqNote":"0"},
     {"PhotoLabel":"choice1-Photos1","PhotoValues":"","reqPhoto":"0"},
     {"DropLabel":"choice1-DropDown1","DropOptions":["choice1-DropDown1-op1","choice1-DropDown1-op2"],"DropSel":"","reqDrop":"0"},
     {"PhotoLabel":"choice1-Photos2","PhotoValues":"","reqPhoto":"0"},
     {"DropLabel":"choice1-DropDown2","DropOptions":["choice1-DropDown2-op1","choice1-DropDown2-op2","choice1-DropDown2-op3"],"DropSel":"","reqDrop":"0"}
    ]
   },
   {"label":"choice2","sel":0,"notification":0,
    "subOptions":[
     {"DropLabel":"choice2-dropDown1","DropOptions":["choice2-dropDown1-op1"],"DropSel":"","reqDrop":"0"}
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
];
if(data)
{
  $.each( data, function( k, v ) {
    var $currentField = $('#form-fields .field').last();
    var subType=v['type'];
    $currentField.find('.field-label').val(v['label']);
    if (v['choices']) {
      $.each( v['choices'], function( k, v ) {
        $currentField.find('.choices ul').append(addChoice(subType));
        $currentField.find('.sub-choices ul').empty();
        $currentField.find('.choice-label').last().val(v['label']);
        if(v['subOptions'])
        {
          $.each( v['subOptions'], function( sk, sv ) {
            if(sv['NoteLabel'])
            {
              $currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('.parentbox').append('<div  style="background:#eee;margin:10px;padding:10px;border:0px solid #fd7e14;"><label for="sub-text" style="display:inline-block; float:left;" class="sub_textarea_label">Notes Label/Question?</label><br/><textarea  style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;" name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" rows="3" cols="40" placeholder="label for notes">'+sv['NoteLabel']+'</textarea><div>');
            }
            if(sv['PhotoLabel'])
            {
              $currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('.parentbox').append('<div  style="background:#eee;margin:10px;padding:10px;border:0px solid #fd7e14;"><label for="sub-photo" style="display:inline-block; float:left;" class="sub_photos_label">Photos Label/Question?</label><br/><input type="text" name="choice_image" class="sub_photos" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;" size="50" placeholder="label for photos" value="'+sv['PhotoLabel']+'"/></div>');
            }

            if(sv['DropLabel'])
            {
              $currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('.parentbox').append('<div style="background:#eee;margin:10px;padding:10px;border:0px solid #fd7e14;"><label  for="sub-drop" style="display:inline-block; float:left;" class="sub_drop_label">Dropdown Label/Question:</label><br/><textarea  class="sub-field-label" style=" display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;" cols="40" placeholder="Label for dropdown">'+sv['DropLabel']+'</textarea><div class="sub-choices"><ul  style="list-style-type:decimal;" class="subList" ></ul></div> </div>');
              if(sv['DropOptions'])
              {
                $.each( sv['DropOptions'], function( dk,dv ){ 
                  var li = $('<li></li>');                                                                   li.html('Test-'+dv);
                  $currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().append(dv+'<br/>');  
                 // $currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().find("ul").append(li); 
                 //$currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().find('ul').append(li);
                // $currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().find('ul.subList').append(li);
                 //$currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().find('.subList').append(li);
                 //$currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().find('ul.subList').prepend(li);
                });
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

function addChoice(subType) {
  if(subType=="sub-drop")
  {
    return '' +
    '<li>' + 
    '<label style="color:#fd7e14;">Add Choice: ' +
    '<input type="text" class="sub-choice-label">' +
    '</label>' +
    '</li>' ; 
  }
  if(subType=="dropdown")
  {
    return '' +
    '<li>' + 
    '<label style="color:#fd7e14;">Add Choice: ' +
    '<input type="text" class="choice-label"> ' +
    '</label>' +
    '<label class="add-sub-choice">'+
    '</label>' +
    '<div style="border:none;" class="parentbox" >'+    
    '</div>' +
    '</li>' ;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sjfb">
<div id="form-fields" class="ui-sortable"> 
<div class="field ui-sortable-handle" data-type="dropdown" style="display: block;">

<fieldset>
<legend>
<h6 style="color:#007bff;">Dropdown List</h6>
</legend>
<label>Field Label/Question:
<textarea class="field-label" style="white-space: pre-wrap;height:auto;width: 100%;" cols="50">Dropdown</textarea>
</label>
<div class="choices">
   <ul style="list-style-type:decimal;" class="ui-sortable">
   </ul>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Everything is working except to append `DropOptions` to existing `ul` tag. The above code appended the `DropOptions` to `div.sub-choices`. I need to append the `DropOptions` to `ul.subList`.

I have commented the options I tried to append here:

```
if(sv['DropOptions'])
{
    $.each( sv['DropOptions'], function( dk,dv ){ 
      var li = $('<li></li>');                                                                   
      li.html('Test-'+dv);
      $currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().append(dv+'<br/>');  
      // $currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().find("ul").append(li); 
      //$currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().find('ul').append(li);
      // $currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().find('ul.subList').append(li);
      //$currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().find('.subList').append(li);
      //$currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().find('ul.subList').prepend(li);
    });
}
```

Please help me to find an option to append the li tag.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Using the above code `DropOptions` append to `div.sub-choices` like the above picture. I need to append the `li` tag to `ul` tag inside `div.sub-choices`

Comment: Would you give me the part in the HTML snippet where you want the <li> tag to be appended to? You may just have a problem in using the selector.

Comment: @JustinPaulPaño Everything is appended from json array  using jquery to <div class="choices">

Comment: I have a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/k4r13zpx/ with little more code

Comment: I know. What I am asking is where in the HTML page do you want the <li> tag to be appended to? Just give me where do you want it to be placed.

Comment: Can you put a screenshot in the question and highlight that part by putting it in a box?

Comment: Ok. I'll try to solve.

Comment: I still can't get it. Where do you want to put the <li> tag? What specific element in the page? Don't put too many elements on the screenshot.

Comment: I have updated the image. I need to iterate through DropOtions in the json array and put the options in ul tag inside $currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices')

Comment: $currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('.parentbox').append('<div style="background:#eee;margin:10px;padding:10px;border:0px solid #fd7e14;"><label  for="sub-drop" style="display:inline-block; float:left;" class="sub_drop_label">Dropdown Label/Question:</label><br/><textarea  class="sub-field-label" style=" display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;" cols="40" placeholder="Label for dropdown">'+sv['DropLabel']+'</textarea><div class="sub-choices"><ul  style="list-style-type:decimal;" class="subList" ></ul></div> </div>');


This is the ul tag appending code

Comment: Am I correct in my assumption that you want to put the <li> in your screenshot below 3. Add Choice?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I need to put the li tags under choice1-DropDown2. And choice1-DropDown2-op1,choice1-DropDown2-op2,choice1-DropDown2-op3 should be in li tags.

Comment: The JSFiddle is different than the code that you presented above. I cannot formulate the answer.

Comment: Jsfiddle is with little more code. https://jsfiddle.net/dywjzf34/1/ Here is one with exactly same code in the question

Comment: You can see if(sv['DropOptions']) {$.each( sv['DropOptions'], function( dk,dv ) { in the code. That is where I need to append li tags

Comment: How is the result of that first jsFiddle different to what you are trying to do? It appears to append options when clicked.

Comment: yes, I am creating a dynamic one and the json array is stored in the database used to store previously inserted options. I have problems only for appending to li tags from json array.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dywjzf34/3/  and  https://jsfiddle.net/bgw6hadq/3/ are the new two jsfiddles.

Comment: I now get your point using the latest fiddle. Please wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not finding the correct element to append these options to because of the selector you have used. The space in your jQuery selector `$currentField.find('.choices li')` will match each `li` element descending from an element with the `choices` class. This means that it picks up `li` elements in your `sub-choices` div.

Try changing `$currentField.find('.choices li').last()` to `$currentField.find('.choices > ul > li').last()`to only get the last `li` in the `choices` div.

Additionally, your code then clears these sub-choices when it loops for the second question. Remove `$currentField.find('.sub-choices ul').empty();` to stop this.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srcqa9gj/)

The rest of your selectors will need to be checked for the same issue as per your comment regarding the additional choices. This particular one can be fixed by changing `$currentField.find('.choices ul').append(addChoice(subType));` to `$currentField.find('.choices > ul').append(addChoice(subType));`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I can see an additional empty add choice at the end of each choice. Can we remove this? I was trying to remove it using $currentField.find('.sub-choices ul').empty();

Comment: It's the same issue in another spot, I've updated the answer/jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$currentField.find('.choices li').last().find('div.parentbox  div.sub-choices').last().find('ul').append('<li>'+dv+'</li>');
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have tried this and I am not getting the options in li tag properly